Can the openapi-generator library generate Python clients that import custom schemas?
I am using the openapi-generator library to generate Python clients for my REST API.
Is it possible to import some schemas instead of generating them? The documentation says it is possible if I provide the importMappings and schemaMappings settings. Neither of them work.
When I generated Java clients for my API the importMappings did not work, but I managed to import custom classes with schemaMappings.
I opened an issue on the library's GitHub page with the steps to reproduce.
I think the importMappings are not a thing in Python according to the source code.
// clear import mapping (from default generator) as python does not use it
// at the moment
importMapping.clear();

Has anyone managed to use either these settings successfully to generate Python clients?

I defined custom templates for the api and the model moustache files. It works in my case but it's not ideal
